# Container starts and immediately stops when mounted to a volume

Tags: c#, .net, docker, containers

I have the most basic console application which logs messages to a location in container. I just want that messages to be written to a persistance volume located in my docker host.

Container - windows container

OS - Windows 10

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
       string path = @"c:\exe\MyTest.txt";
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string createText = $" {i} + Hello and Welcome"+ Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(path, createText);
            i++;
        }      
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# getting base image
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest

ADD ./bin/debug /exe/

VOLUME c:/data   # this line creates issue

ENTRYPOINT ["/exe/BackendService.bat"]
```

**BackendService.bat**

```
start c:\exe\ConsoleApp16.exe
```

**Command Run:**

```
docker build -t fridayimg1:1.0 .   

docker run {ImageID}
```

Everything works fine if I do not give `Volume` info in the DockerFile.

P.S: So, the problem is as soon as I start mentioning `Volume` the container starts and then exits. When I do `docker {containerID} inspect`, I can see that 
the container `c:/data` has been mounted to a physical location in my Volumes folder.

Question: Why my container starts and then exits immediately. But as soon as I remove the volume tag, it continues to work fine and loop and writes messages to `MyTest.txt` file inside the container.

Comment: What do you see in `docker logs`?

Comment: You cannot use absolute paths in Dockerfile. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the messages to be written in host's volume, in persistence store

Comment: That `VOLUME` directive cannot do that; nothing in a Dockerfile other than a `COPY` or `ADD` references the host at all.  It will have some surprising side effects and I would recommend just removing it.  @Mihai ‘s answer will work just fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the volume when you run the container, not when you build it (in Dockerfile).

```
docker run -v ./data:/data <your image>
```

This will map a folder "data" in your current folder to the path "/data" in your container.